# Understanding maxmin function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through functions in [Learning Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_Python), this one is giving me a little trouble understanding, was wondering if anyone could help me understand it better, more specifically the `if test(arg, res)`
When I run the first function, it doesn't matter what I put as the first argument, then the second argument has to be a list, and it just spits the list back as written. I'm confused on when you combine the functions and print them together how it gives the max and min.

```
def minmax(test, *args):
    res = args[0]
    for arg in args[1:]:
        if test(arg, res):
            res = arg
    return res
def lessthan(x, y): return x < y
def grtrthan(x, y): return x > y
print(minmax(lessthan, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3))
print(minmax(grtrthan, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3))
```

Comment: "then the second argument has to be a list" Are you sure you're reading it properly?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be misunderstanding how the [starred function argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) works. When you call your function as `minmax(something, [1, 2, ...])`, `args` becomes a tuple of one element equal to `[1, 2, ...]`. Therefore the body of the loop never gets executed and the value of `test` does not matter. The function is supposed to be invoked as `minmax(something, 1, 2, ...)`. This way `args` gets the value `(1, 2, ...)` and the loop goes through its elements.

*Clarification:* The answer is based on what you wrote. Your code snippet is correct and works exactly as intended.

Comment: Where are the arguments for the lessthan and grtrthan functions coming from? They need two right?

Comment: In your code `test` becomes equal to `lessthan` or `grtrthan`. It then gets called with two arguments.

Comment: Could you explain the for loop? How come when I change the res = arg to res > arg or res < arg both prints give me 4 and 4?

Comment: When you make these changes the lines do not do anything (`res=arg` **assigns** a value to `res`; `res > arg` evaluates to `True` or `False` and the value gets discarded), so `res` keeps its initially assigned value of `args[0]` (which happens to be `4` in your case)

Comment: Something is just flying over my head. Thanks for the help, it makes more sense now. But when I run the lessthan and grtrthan functions on there own they give me true or false, and when I run the minmax function it gives me whatever I put for *args. I still cant figure out how the combination gives a min and max. Im going to feel like an idiot when I figure it out :(

Comment: It might help to use an IDE that lets you go through the code step by step, or just put in a bunch of `print`s and see how the variables change after every line.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read that book so I don't know the context, but it looks that function (`minmax`) is not well named.  It does not return two values, it only returns one -- and which one depends on the testing function you give it.  If you pass in the `lessthan` function:

```
print(minmax(lessthan, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3))
```

you'll get `1`, and if you pass in the `grtrthan` function:

```
print(minmax(grtrthan, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3))
```

you'll get `6`.